# How to avoid "No Disk in Drive" error during batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm running a batch file that searches each hard drive letter for the existence of a particular file in the root of that drive.

Example:

```
@echo off

for %%a in (C D E F G H I J K) do if exist %%a:\myfile.txt set DEST=%%a:

XCOPY "my app.exe" "%DEST%\" /i /y
```

However, if there's no disk in one of the drives being checked (especially Card readers), I get an error message, `THERE IS NO DISK IN DRIVE`, etc... and the batch is halted, requiring user input,and clicking "continue" 2 or 3 times the file copied successfully.

I want to avoid this and yet still searches all possible drive letters...

Ideally, I want to suppress any halting as well as any error messages...

PS: the `myfile.txt` is always in fixed drive only

Answer (score 0):

for checking if the disk is inserted you might want to try

to check if a directory exists, in your case the root of the removable drive, try this.

```
    IF EXIST %%a:\NUL ECHO %%a:\ exists!
```

Comment: thanks,but what about the "myfile.txt" I'm searching and set destination for xcopy ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one like, using PA.'s answer in part...

for %a in (C D E F G H I J K) do if exist %a:\ if exist %a:\myfile.txt xcopy "my app.exe" %a:\ /i /y

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year since this problem, but here's the solution:

```
@echo off

FOR %%a IN (C D E F G H I J K) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%a:\myfile.txt" (
        SET DEST=%%a:
        goto :found
    )
)

:found
XCOPY ..\"app1.exe" "%DEST%\Softwares\" /i /y
XCOPY ..\"app2.exe" "%DEST%\Softwares\" /i /y
```